# Couldn't package a cron job using sbt-native-packager when building a deb bundle

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, akka, sbt-native-packager

I am trying to package a cron as part of my debian package (https://github.com/indykish/megam_akka.git).

The debian package is built using the sbt-native-packager.
I placed the cron script inside my bin directory as here https://github.com/indykish/megam_akka/blob/master/bin/megamherk.cron.d

I changed my build.sbt to pickup the megamher.cron.d as here
https://github.com/indykish/megam_akka/blob/master/build.sbt

I have attached the snippet of code here:

```
 linuxPackageMappings in Debian <+= (baseDirectory) map { bd =>
 (packageMapping((bd / "bin/herk_stash") -> "/usr/share/megamherk/bin/herk_stash")
 withUser "root" withGroup "root" withPerms "0755")
 }

linuxPackageMappings in Debian <+= (baseDirectory) map { bd =>
(packageMapping((bd / "bin/megamherk.cron.d") -> "/etc/cron.d/megamherk")
withUser "root" withGroup "root" withPerms "0755")
}
```

I ran:

```
sbt clean compile

sbt dist:dist

sbt debian:packageBin
```

The generated debian bundle inside the target directory doesn't have the cron bundled.

I referred this debian documentation (http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#crond)

Am I missing something here ? How do I make sbt-native-package pickup a cron job ?

Comment: I think you should put your bin directory inside src because baseDirectory in your snippet is source dir

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to package simple files is to use the default directory structure.

```
src/linux/...
```

In your case you would put your file in

```
src/linux/etc/cron.d/megamherk
```

You locale settings will be reapplied. So if **megamherk** is executable it will stay executable.

If this doesn't work for you open a [ticket](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/new) with a small test case.

cheers,
Muki